# react-heatpack error: events.js:85 throw er;

Tags: reactjs

heatpack was running fine until today, here's the error
`events.js:85
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at net.js:1280:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:81:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:99:10)`

no other server (nginx, node server...) is running.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide your your running configuration, it's a binding problem.

Comment: it's just one short .js file (30 lines) with react code

Comment: How do you have set the ip/address of the server?

Comment: I didn't set anything heatpack sets it is not a nodejs app.